# Using event as view exclude filter in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an event that triggers from my tag manager every time someone clicks a certain URL link. This event appears to be tracking properly in GA. However, I am attempting to create a filtered view that excludes traffic that triggers this event. When I use the Filter Verification I get:

"This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small."

Indeed it does not change my data. I am using the event label as the field field/pattern if that makes a difference. Any suggestions?

[image: Filter Settings]

[image: Event Label Settings]

Comment: Attach the screenshot of your filter, also is it UA or GA4?

Comment: UA, I have added screen captures of my filter and the event. I should also note, this does appear to remove the event from registering in the filtered view, but not the traffic that performs the event. Those numbers are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are issues with this question. But first, the answer is: filters aren't meant to remove more than particular hits. They aren't meant to remove sessions or users. Only hits. But there's a hackaround.

Now, more points:

1. You don't exclude "traffic". Traffic is not precise enough to be useful here. You have to decide what you want to exclude: an event, a session or a user. Or something inbetween, but then you need to define it properly.
2. A session in Google's understanding is really a bit different from what it seems like. It is custom to believe that a session is a series of interactional events with less than 30 minutes (configurable) inbetween. Not quite. If your source changes, that's a new session. Bear with me.
3. You... can hack around it if you really need to. By "painting" users or sessions. You do it by setting a specific custom dimension (user- or session-level) and then delete all events that have that custom dimension set using a view filter. The CD will be backfilled, so the filter should clean stuff close to how you expect it to do.

However! GA is... a little bit odd with how they record sessions and users. There may occur a situation when you end up having users or sessions with no events in them. However, if you find this issue at play, you still can export the data to BQ and query it properly. You may find that export cleaner.